# How to select "From" field with qualifier in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working with a database that has field name "From" and any time I try to write a query like this:

```
Select [Tab.From] AS FromAddress From MyAddresses Tab
```

I get invalid column name "Tab.From".

However if I do `Select [From]` it works.

I believe it has something to do with "From" being a keyword in sql. Is there any way I can access it in select statement?

Comment: `select "From"... ` (ANSI SQL version), or `select [From] ...` (product specific version).

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `Select [From] AS FromAddress From MyTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a truly bad column name (& yes it certainly is a reserved word)

```
SELECT t.[From] AS FromAddress 
FROM MyAddresses AS t
```

Comment: Make sure you ALWAYS use table.[column] or alias.[column] with that bad name. It is going to give you a LOT of grief and personally I would move heaven and earth to get that column name changed.

Comment: Oh I will for sure change that in the new design, whatever it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT [From] AS FromAddress FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
Select MyTable.From AS FromAddress From MyTable
```

You are not defining your alias correct. Try this method.

Comment: Save mine is working, he did something more be adding an alias to the table also. Its sad that you say it's wrong and you don't even test. One man answer working doesn't make others wrong, or not working.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_alias_column

Comment: That did not work for me. It is as simple as that. "From" is a reserved keyword so you need to wrap it around [].

Comment: I know From is a reserved keyword, so why use bad practice in your database design? You can avoid these problems by just making the right database structure.

Comment: I did not create it, I inherited the design. But you have to admit that your answer is not valid.

Comment: I admit. But you should admit that a bad start is just a lot more pointless work. Good luck with  the project.